# Which package can easily write a graph, as an arbitrary curve or area, just for indication

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

Which package can easily write a graph, as an arbitrary curve or area, just for indication? The circle and ellipse don't be considered for their particular shape. TIKZ's Bézier curve is too non-intuitive to use.

Comment: TikZ with the `to[out=angle,in=angle]`. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/drawing-a-hypergraph/1195#1195. But you should give us more details about what you want.

Comment: @Caramdir: I learn a lot from the link. [Here is the example](http://imgur.com/7230u), draw this kind of figure intuitively and easily.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 19):

You can use `TikZ` `\draw plot` functionality to get smoothed lines and polygons. `TikZ` works directly with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz \draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.1) (2,0.3) (2,1.4) (1.5,2.5) (0.8,2.5) (0.3,1.2) (-0.2,0.6) } node at (1,1) {Area};
\tikz \draw plot [smooth,tension=1.2] coordinates {(0,1) (0.75,0.5) (1.5,0.9) (2,0) (2.5,0)} node at (1,0) {Line};
\end{document}
```

[image: smooth polygon and line]

---

Or, as Andrew Stacey suggested, using random coordinates. You can play around with the seed and the factors for the random part. `rnd` returns a number between 0 and 1, `rand` returns a number between -1 and 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{3}
\draw plot [smooth cycle, samples=8,domain={1:8}] (\x*360/8+5*rnd:0.5cm+1cm*rnd) node at (0,0) {Area};
\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\draw plot [smooth, samples=5,domain={1:5},xshift=1cm] (\x+0.5*rnd,0.75*rand) node at (4,-0.75) {Line};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: random shapes]

Comment: Now throw in a randomiser on the coordinates!

Answer (score 9):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
  \psccurve[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20!red!10](0,0)(2,0.5)(4,1)(6,5)(3,3)(2,5)
  \rput(3,2){\Huge\textbf{Curve}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work fine with the normal `latex` compiler. I'm just wondering what the special reason is to use `xelatex`? I do not know it very well and like to learn more about it.

Comment: @Martin: The issue is that `pstricks` won't work with `pdflatex`.  Yes, it should work with the dvi-producing `latex`.  But it also works with `xelatex`.

Comment: @Martin: with `xelatex` you'll get directly the pdf. ALternatively you can run `pdflatex -shell-escape` when using `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`

Comment: and xelatex does not require shell escape as pdflatex does? why not?

Comment: @pluton because XeLaTeX has a native support of PostScript specials, PDFLaTeX does not.

Comment: @tohecz: It is not really a _native_ support. It does nearly the same as the package `auto-pst-pdf` for `pdflatex`.