# How to draw a smooth random blob with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, random-numbers

How can I draw a smooth, "natural" looking blob with TikZ?

My approach

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [] (0,0)node[circle,draw,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=.3cm,amplitude=1cm},rounded corners=.1cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

fails because the ends of the circle are not connected. Using the `path has corner=false` flag does not help either. Is there a possibility of doing this at all?

Comment: Related: [Tips for creating semi-random blob in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35534)/

Comment: Also related: [Which package can easily write a graph, as an arbitrary curve or area, just for indication](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13473/which-package-can-easily-write-a-graph-as-an-arbitrary-curve-or-area-just-for)

Comment: Thanks. @Torbjørn T.: In the semi-random blob example the same problem of non-smoothly connected path ends occurs. @Jake: Using `\pgfmathsetseed{1}\draw plot [smooth cycle, samples=8,domain={1:8}] (\x*360/8+5*rnd:0.5cm+1cm*rnd) node at (0,0) {}` from the second link works perfectly fine!

Comment: This is a problem that only `hobby` can solve I think. See this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/curve-through-a-sequence-of-points-with-metapost-and-tikz