# Draw a set in set (subset) with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a set in a set with M being the subset and N the other set. I want them to look like "clouds", not perfect circles. I only came up with drawing perfect circles using the \draw (circle) thing, anyone got an idea?

Best regards,

Dan

Comment: Is this enough http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13473/which-package-can-easily-write-a-graph-as-an-arbitrary-curve-or-area-just-for ?