# How to draw a hypergraph (forest)?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, graphs

How can I draw a hypergraph structure (a.k.a. forest) like this:

[image: forest]

(Note: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/drawing-a-hypergraph), of course, since that drawing is very different.)

Comment: how did you create the original? (i am interested in making something similar to your graph and would like to know how others make theirs).

Comment: I didn't create it. I found it in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.164.1174&rank=3 (see PDF link on the right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I give only the structure but you can make this by hand "easily". I don't have enough time to finish the graph but you need only to define some nodes and then you put the arrows. The last arrows are simple.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(A){$NPB_{0,1}$} ;
\node(B) at ($(A)+(2,0)$){$CC_{1,2}$} ; 
\node(C) at ($(B)+(2,0)$){$P_{1,2}$} ;   
\node(D) at ($(C)+(2,0)$){$NPB_{2,3}$} ;   
\node(E) at ($(D)+(2,0)$){$VV_{3,4}$} ;   
\node(F) at ($(E)+(2,0)$){$AS_{4,5}$} ;   
\node(G) at ($(F)+(2,0)$){$NPB_{5,6}$} ; 
\node(Deb) at (5,8){$IP_{0,6}$};
\node(FF) at ($(F)+(0,4)$){$VBP_{3,6}$} ;  
\node(BB) at ($(B)+(0,5)$){$NP_{0,3}$} ; 
\draw[->] (A) to[out=90,in=180] (3,7)--(4,7) to[out=0,in=-90](Deb); 
\draw[rounded corners=2cm,
       dashed,->] (FF)to[out=90,in=-60] ($(Deb)+(.5,0)$);
\draw[dashed,->] (A) to [in =-90,out =90](BB);
\draw[dashed,->] (BB) to [in =-180,out =90] ++(2,1) to [out=0,in=-70]($(Deb)+(.5,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! It doesn't compile for me though. It complains about the `++(2,1)` in the last draw command: `( expected` after the first plus. Sorry if this is a trivial thing to fix, but I don't speak tikz (yet).

Comment: @Franck Strange error ! the code compiles for me. What you get with : `\tikz\draw[in =-180,out =90] (0,3) to ++(9,-2);` ? Which pgf version do you use ?

Comment: This figure looks great, but I also get the same error on Ubuntu with texlive and on Windows with Miktex. On Ubuntu the pgf version is 2.00-1. I get "! Package tikz Error: ( expected." error when substituting the command in the above comment.

Comment: You can install pgf 2.10  on your personal folder texm