# Latex code to create figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphics, diagrams

I want to draw hypergraph on LaTex, here what I do :

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.6}}

\node [venn circle = white] (A) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node [venn circle = white] (B) at (60:4cm) {$2$};
\node [venn circle = white] (C) at (0:4cm) {$3$};
\node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$1$}; 
\node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$3$};   
\node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$2$};   
\node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$1,2,3,4$};

\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Then it will produce

[image]

I try to learn this [LaTex code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/drawing-a-hypergraph) to create what I want, but i don't understand it. I hope anyone can help me. thank you

Comment: What would you like to change? You want the lavels $e_i$ outside. You also want the "dot before the numbers? And also, when you write `1...1` what do you exactly mean with that?

Comment: Do you just want the "shape" of the sets to be slightly irregular rather than be perfect circles as in the OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find various example of how to draw irregular shapes here: [How to draw a irregular circle(shape)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126144/how-to-draw-a-irregular-circleshape)

My MWE is based on [Guilherme Zanotelli's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350388/101651).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\tikzset{
    mydot/.style={
        circle, inner sep =1pt, fill=black
    },
    irreg/.style={
        decoration={random steps, amplitude=2pt, segment length=10pt, post length=10pt, pre length=10pt}, decorate, rounded corners
    },
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (centro);
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$1$}, mydot, below right=16pt and -8pt of centro] (1) {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$2$}, mydot, above right=2pt and 12pt of 1] (2) {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$3$}, mydot, below=12pt of 1] (3) {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$4$}, mydot, above right=2pt and 12pt of 3] (4) {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$1$}, mydot, above=6ex of centro] {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$2$}, mydot, below right=12ex and 4em of centro] {};
        \node[label={[label distance=-3pt]45:$3$}, mydot, below left=12ex and 4em of centro] {};
        \node [left=7em of centro] (a) {$1\dots1$}; 
        \node [right=7em of centro] (b) {$2\dots2$}; 
        \node [below=20ex of centro] (c) {$3\dots3$}; 
        \draw[irreg] ([xshift=-6em]centro) ellipse (10em and 16ex);
        \draw[irreg] ([xshift=6em]centro) ellipse (10em and 16ex);
        \draw[irreg] ([yshift=-16ex]centro) ellipse (6em and 20ex);
        \node[font=\Large,below left=10ex and 14em of centro] {$e_{1}$}; 
        \node[font=\Large,below right=10ex and 14em of centro] {$e_{2}$}; 
        \node[font=\Large,below=37ex of centro] {$e_{3}$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user326307 You could use `\resizebox`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4340/101651. If you have any problem in resizing, please ask a new question with some blind text explaing how you would like your output, we will be happy to answer. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain the reason. Since the OP accepted my answer, perhaps this was what he needed.